# What benefits does daemonizing give me?

Tags: ssh, daemon

If I start something like uWSGI via SSH with my normal login user (assuming I should), and "daemonize" it, does that mean I can log out of SSH and uWSGI will remain running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a daemon is a program that is a background process (that is, a process that doesn't involve any interaction on your part in doing what it does), and persists until the process is killed (lets say via an init script you wrote for this very thing), then yes. If you daemonize uWGSI, it will run until you kill the process spawned by the daemon.

You might want to consider looking into [writing some init scripts](http://www.google.co.uk/?q=init%20scrip#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=init+script&fp=3b6b42e17dd83c7b) to handle this process for you, rather than daemonizing a program manually.